# document.body.style.backgroundColor doesn't work with external CSS style sheet

Tags: javascript, html, css

Could anyone tell me why `document.body.style.backgroundColor` doesn't work with external CSS style sheet?
I mean: when I have

```
body
{
    background-color: red;   
}
```

in my css style sheet javascript alert `alert(document.body.style.backgroundColor);` shows empty string.
Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/o9cqzdnt/59/).

but when I have

```
<body style="background-color: red;"></body>
```

it shows (as it should) "red".
Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/o9cqzdnt/60/).

I would appreciate a good explanation and even more an answer how to fix the first example.

Comment: Have you tired to google [js element actual style](https://www.google.ru/search?q=js+element+actual+style)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.style` property on a DOM element returns a [`CSSStyleDeclaration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) for that particular element. By definition of a `.style` access, it is the styles of the element itself.
`style=` attribute controls the same value, thus you see the result.

However, CSS applied using a selector are not directly a property of an element. Consider the CSS `p { color: red }`. This CSS applies to multiple elements, and as such, make no sense being overrideable on a level of a particular element.

What you are looking for is `window.getComputedStyle` to get a read-only view on the element's current styles: `window.getComputedStyle(document.body).backgroundColor` indeed returns a correct value, as seen in the [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o9cqzdnt/66/).

Comment: Thanks, that's the explanation I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

you are using jquery buddy

try this it will give rgb value

```
alert($('body').css('background-color'));
```

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/o9cqzdnt/63/)

if you want hex value try this

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/o9cqzdnt/67/)

Comment: And when you change the library in jsfiddle to "none" you get the result you expect

Comment: "you are using jquery" — The question doesn't mention jQuery, the `jquery` tag is not used, the `javascript` tag says *Unless a tag for a framework or library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected*

Comment: but in his js fiddle she has linked jquery

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var element =     document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];                     
var style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
var bgColor    = style.getPropertyValue('background-color');
```